# Why my list ObservableCollection never is refresh?

Tags: xamarin.forms

Why never refresh my list? i am using list observable

```
private ObservableCollection<Actor> actors = new ObservableCollection<Actor>();
        public ObservableCollection<Actor> Actors
        {
            get
            {
                return actors;
            }
            set
            {

                    actors = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged(() => Actors);

            }
        }
for (int i=0; i<actors.Count;i++) {
                actors[i].IsHidden = false;

            }
```

only its refresh when i clean and reinsert my all datas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `ObservableCollection` will only Notify of a change when its items change, that is, as you stated when items are added or removed from the collection.

If you want to also be notified when certain properties of your class change you will need to make that class implement `INotifYPropertyChange` interface.

In your specific case, you will need to update `Actor` class.

```
public class Actor : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  ...

  private bool isHidden;
  public bool IsHidden 
  {
    get {return isHidden}
    set 
    {
        isHidden = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => IsHidden);
    }
  }

  ...

}
```

You will have to do this for all the properties you want to listen for changes as you did in your ViewModel.

Probably you already have done this, but I suggest you add a `BaseViewModel` which is basically a class with the `INotifyPropertyChanged` implementation and make your ViewModels and also this class and any other class you want this behavior to extend it.

Hope this helps.-